# Math for Gaussian noise on top of another Gaussian noise

Tags: dataset, gaussian-process, signal-processing, noise

I have worked on this project for a while and I have some results. However, I want to communicate in my paper the mathematics involved.

When an image is introduced with 11 standard deviations, this is how it looks like:
[image: Gauss]

This is the 11std image with 11std Gaussian noise introduced
[image: GaussGauss]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What math operations are going on here? I was about to write that adding noise on top of noise is literally addition (so 11std + 11std = 22std). But I really don't think that's the case

Comment: It is literally addition: of random variables.  Adding one-pixel Gaussian noise $n$ times is (up to discretization error) identical to adding $\sqrt{n}$-pixel Gaussian noise once.

Comment: Thank you so much, @whuber